# How to securely connect to my MongoDB replicaset?

Tags: mongodb, security

I have a MongoDB replica set that recently got hacked and hackers deleted my database. I don't want this to happen again. What I would like is, only a handful of programs like my MongoDB replica set members, node.js program, and my terminal should be the only one that can communicate with the database and no other program. How should I go about it?

For starters, I have set bind_ip property in my mongod.conf to be [127.0.0.1,ip_1,ip_2,ip_3], one of the IP is it's own IP. Is this enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I identified it is possible to securely connect all my servers. I found the answer with [this article on setting up ufw on my ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-16-04). Then I established mongo replica set connection between them. Now the challenge came in establishing [Keyfile access control in existing replica set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/#security-replset-auth-access-control)
which I found to be difficult [Because of this issue on Github in mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4900). 
Using SSL/TLS is easy on the native driver than it is on the mongoose. Plus native driver is much faster than any ORM. So in a phase wise manner I replaced mongoose with mongodb native driver and introduced key file access. Maybe in later versions of mongoose, they might introduce this access.